# Where does a Fire tablet store its device name?

Tags: amazon-fire-os

When I first buy a Fire tablet, before I set it up, its name is set to "My Fire".

After I register it with Amazon, its name changes to "Creede's 30th Fire" (or some other positive integer) until I change it to something more to my liking, either under "Device Options/Change Your Device Name" or on Amazon's site somewhere under "Your Account / Apps and More / Your Devices".

However, I might not want to register the device with Amazon. In fact I might want to remove as much of Amazon's hooverware† as I can get away with and move the tablet closer to a stock Android experience. If it do that, though, the tablet's name is stuck at "My Fire" and the option to change it in "Device Options" is grayed out.

Is there a setting somewhere in Fire OS that I can edit to change the device's name? It seems like there should be something analogous to /etc/hostname in Linux, but Fire OS has no "hostname" file in /etc (which is a symlink to /system/etc) and grepping through the files in /etc didn't turn up anything.

† Hooverware (n). Applications designed to suck as much money out of you as possible, in much the same way that a vacuum cleaner is designed to suck up as much dirt as possible. Named for a well-known American brand of vacuum cleaner.